# Firebug shows symbol in Styles under content

Tags: css

How is it possible to show the symbol under Styles if the parameter content is used? Sample:  Firebug shows content: "";

Answer (score 0):

**MDN**

> The `content` CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after`
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
>   using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.

`content` can have text, symbol (unicode) and images.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)